# VB.NET: PictureBox view range?

Tags: vb.net, view, picturebox

I two pictureboxes in my application: One that is mostly just a background image, and another which you can move around changing some settings.

However, depending on my settings (X,Y,Width,Height), a fragment or all of the second picturebox might be "out" of the first picturebox. I don't want that.

Basically, if there is anything in the second picturebox's that is not over the first picturebox, I don't want to show that fragment. I want to cut it.

If I move the second picturebox back inside the first picturebox, then I can see all of it again.

Think of the first picturebox as a "view range"

Comment: Tip: take a screenshot and add it in your question. It would be easier to visualize what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

I set the second picturebox's parent to the first picturebox. Now the second picturebox is cut if it leaves the first picturebox's area.

Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if these threads can help : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351054/c-winform-ui-componets-layer-order) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641406/z-index-in-winforms)